# Отправка Post запроса на Random.org

Tags: jquery, json, api, случайные-числа

Нужна помощь с Random.org API. Отправляю на сайт random.org POST запрос с JSON объектом, который должен мне вернуть JSON объект с сгенерированными случайными числами, но возвращается ошибка -32700 которая обозначает, что я отправил не правильный JSON объект, но он скопирован из официальной документации, так что в нем не должно быть ошибки.

Сам код:

```
var data =  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "generateIntegers",
    "params": {
    "apiKey": "c2ddbb2d-b031-4e65-8532-a5c10036fc77",
        "n": 6,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 6,
        "replacement": true
    },
    "id": 42
};

$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(res) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
  }
});
```

Есть разбирающиеся в этой теме?

**UPD**
Если добавить в ajax строку `dataType: 'application/json'`, то success вообще не срабатывает и alert ничего не выводит.

Comment: C jQuery особо не знаком, но Вы уверены, что `$.ajax()` при отправке сериализует Ваш объект именно в формат JSON?

Comment: @Yaant Так переменная data уже содержит json объект

Comment: _"но он скопирован из официальной документации"_ - ссылку покажи.

Comment: @Qwerity [Вот](https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/)

Comment: @Dantessss С чего бы это был JSON? JSON — это _строка_. А у Вас там самый обычный JavaScript-овский _объект_.

Comment: @Yaant Да, я уже понял ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "generateIntegers",
  "params": {
    "apiKey": "c2ddbb2d-b031-4e65-8532-a5c10036fc77",
    "n": 6,
    "min": 1,
    "max": 6,
    "replacement": true
  },
  "id": 42
};

$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke",
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А почему нужно использовать JSON.stringify(), если data и есть json?

Comment: @Dantessss, без него jQuery всё равно шлёт url-encoded.